# Display issue Ubuntu Server 19.10.1 Raspberry Pi 4 with Xubuntu Desktop

Tags: server, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, raspberrypi

I just setup Ubuntu Server 19.10.1 64-bit server on my Raspberry Pi 4 with the Xubuntu desktop.  I am having display issues with it.  I have two monitors hooked up that work correctly in Raspbian.  Ubuntu does not detect my 2nd monitor.  The main monitor does not display the correct resolution.  It has the  resolution as 1824x984.  The native resolution is 1920x1080.  It does not have the refresh rate either.  It shows 0.0 Hz.  Could somebody help me get both monitors working correctly?  I hope one of the Ubuntu flavors supports the Pi 4 after 20.04 is released.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try/use [Berryboot](https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) and install your Ubuntu via this tool. I also had problems with my monitor. Berryboot seems to set/change values in the config file. After using it my TV was recognized and the resolution was correct.

Another neat feature, you could install more then one OS if you want it.

If you don't want Berryboot, then install it, install Ubuntu, make a copy of the config file and reinstall Ubuntu gain without Berryboot. Change the monitor part with the one from the config file from Berryboot.

You also can change the config file without Berryboot, I tried, but the result was not as good (even with a in depth tutorial).

Also a tip. If you added a SSD to your PI4, there are tuts out there how to copy over your / partition to it, so that you will only boot from the SD-card and the rest of the system gets loaded from an SSD HD. I run a Linux Mint Mate on my PI4 via Berryboot, runs awesome!

I hope that helps to get rid of your problems. Berryboot did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give this a try when 20.04 is released. Hopefully it won’t be too long before they release the raspberry pi version.